# Remove external link icon from image

Tags: html, css, jekyll, font-awesome

I am trying to create a Jekyll blog template. I want to show an font awesome external link icon along with hyperlinks on every article. So I wrote CSS like:

```
#myLink a[href^="//"]:after, 
#myLink a[href^="http://"]:after,
#myLink a[href^="https://"]:after {
content: "\f35d";
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
font-weight: 900;
margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
#myLink a:link {
color: blue;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
#myLink a:visited {
color: hotpink;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
}
#myLink a:hover {
color: green;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
}
#myLink a:active {
color: blue;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

Then I wrote article as follows:

```
<article id="myLink">
.....
....
</article>
```

It works. But if I add Image as an external link

```
![img](https://something.jpg)
```

It will shows **font awesome** external link after image. How can I remove that icon for images?

Comment: I'm not expert in the subject matter, hence comment instead of answer, but my best guess would be, this is caused by copyright issues where the watermark is hard-embedded there because you are using a free version of a font that comes with the copyright without purchase.

Comment: @Rawrplus I am using FontAwesome 5 free, which is under MIT license. We can find this project on official Github account of FontAwesome.

Comment: can't you just add a class to the images and do `content:""` ? or `display:none`?

Comment: @NoobishPro OK. I will try that soon. Can I use not selector instead that?

Comment: @ArunKS sure, but that's less efficient. If you do a `:not` selector, it will check for every element whether or not it is the img. If you just overwrite it for images, it won't do a check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove external link icon from hyperlinked images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892781/remove-external-link-icon-from-hyperlinked-images)

Comment: I just posted an answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892781/remove-external-link-icon-from-hyperlinked-images/54893157#54893157