# Remove external link icon from hyperlinked images

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to find a way to remove the external link icon from hyperlinked images. I want the icon to be appeared after the text links only. I found this [Remove external link icon from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909079/remove-external-link-icon-from-image) but don't any answer over there.

```
#myLink a[href^="//"]:after, 
#myLink a[href^="http://"]:after,
#myLink a[href^="https://"]:after {
    content: "\f35d";
    font-family: "Font Awesome"; 
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what the link markup looks like? Where is the original icon coming from?

Comment: @jerrylow original icon is being come from FontAwesome family. As I have used "content" in the pseudo (:after) element of <a> tag. It just started appearing for all hyperlinked images (<a href="https://example.com/sub-page"><img src="image.png"></a>) too. I want that icon to be removed for only images.

Comment: Can you just remove the content for these selectors

Comment: As a [comment on that question already notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909079/remove-external-link-icon-from-image#comment84828766_48909079), you can just add a class to the anchors that have images, and use `#myLink a[href^="//"]:not(.hasImage)` to target those.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It didn't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I got a way using jquery and CSS. I am posting my solution here just in case, if anyone needs it. I just added a class in  tag using jquery and just add display:none to the psuedo element (:after). See below:

```
$('a').has('img').addClass('hyperlinkedimage');

.hyperlinkedimage { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the future you'll be able to use [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class.

> The `:has()` CSS pseudo-class represents an element if any of the selectors passed as parameters (relative to the :scope of the given element), match at least one element.

The following selector matches only  elements that directly contain an  child:

```
a:has(> img)
```

For now, you'll have to use JavaScripts to do that, jQuery example:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('> img').length) {
        // do something...
    }
});
```